# Adding an ident to multiple repetition results in "local ambiguity: multiple parsing options"

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to build a macro that would be called with a list of function calls (`test2()`) or identifiers (`test3`):

```
invoke!( 
    ["str1", "str2"]: i32 => test1(), test2(), test3, test4; 
    ["str3", "str1"]: i32 => test1(), test3; 
)
```

Right now, it only supports function calls:

```
invoke!( 
    ["str1", "str2"]: i32 => test1(), test2(); 
    ["str3", "str1"]: i32 => test1(); 
)
```

The original macro code:

```
macro_rules! invoke {
    ( $([$($field:expr),*]: $vtype:ty => $($func:ident$args:tt),*; )+ ) => {
        $(
            let x = vec![$($field),*];
            let y = vec![$($func$args),*];
            println!("{:#?}: {:#?}", x, y)
        )+
    };
}
```

When I try to change it to support both forms:

```
macro_rules! invoke {
    ( $([$($field:expr),*]: $vtype:ty => $($func:ident$args:tt),* $($newfunc:ident),*; )+ ) => {
        $(
            let x = vec![$($field),*];
            let y = vec![$($func$args),*];
            let z: Vec<$vtype> = vec![$newfunc()];
            println!("{:#?}: {:#?} [{:#?}]", x, y, z)
        )+
    };
}
```

I get an error:

```
error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs ident ('func') or ident ('newfunc').
  --> src/main.rs:15:34
   |
15 |         ["str1", "str2"]: i32 => test1(), test2(), test3, test4; 
   |                                  ^^^^^
```

I know that it possible to build this macro via `:tt`, but I can't find way how to do it.

[Working code sample](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=macro_rules!%20invoke%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%20%24(%5B%24(%24field%3Aexpr)%2C*%5D%3A%20%24vtype%3Aty%20%3D%3E%20%24(%24func%3Aident%24args%3Att)%2C*%3B%20)%2B%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20vec!%5B%24(%24field)%2C*%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20vec!%5B%24(%24func%24args)%2C*%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%23%3F%7D%3A%20%7B%3A%23%3F%7D%22%2C%20x%2C%20y)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%2B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20test1(val%3A%20i32)%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20val%20*%202%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20test2()%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%2020%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20invoke!(%20%5B%22str1%22%2C%20%22str2%22%5D%3A%20i32%20%3D%3E%20test1(20)%2C%20test2()%3B%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)

[Expected and not working code sample](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=macro_rules!%20invoke%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%20%24(%5B%24(%24field%3Aexpr)%2C*%5D%3A%20%24vtype%3Aty%20%3D%3E%20%24(%24func%3Aident%24args%3Att)%2C*%20%24(%24newfunc%3Aident)%2C*%3B%20)%2B%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20vec!%5B%24(%24field)%2C*%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20vec!%5B%24(%24func%24args)%2C*%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20z%20%3D%20vec!(%24(%24newfunc)%2C*)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%23%3F%7D%3A%20%7B%3A%23%3F%7D%22%2C%20x%2C%20y)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%2B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20test1(val%3A%20i32)%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20val%20*%202%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20test2()%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%2020%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20invoke!(%20%5B%22str1%22%2C%20%22str2%22%5D%3A%20i32%20%3D%3E%20test1(20)%2C%20test2()%2C%20test2%3B%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Could you change how `invoke!` is called instead?

Comment: @kennytm it's presented explicitly in code: 
`invoke!( 
    ["str1", "str2"]: i32 => test1() test2(); 
    ["str3", "str1"]: i32 => test1(); 
)`

Comment: I get errors in your macro - even the one you say is working. Also, can you show what you expect your first example to be transformed into?

Comment: @PeterHall I don't know how you can get errors. I added link to question, it's worked code sample. Through time I added expected sample.

Comment: @mrLSD I mean, instead of `invoke!(["str1"]: i32 => test1(), test2(), test3, test4)`, could you change the syntax to like `invoke!(["str1"]: i32 => {test1() => test3, test2() => test4})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This macro pattern does not make sense:

```
$($func:ident$args:tt),* $($newfunc:ident),*;
```

This says to parse zero or more identifiers (`func`) followed by zero or more identifiers (`newfunc`). If the input was the ident `foo`, then the parser would not be capable of deciding which grammar path to choose as there's a limited about of lookahead (presumably one token).

As pointed out in the comments, the easiest solution is to introduce new syntax to disambiguate the cases.

```
macro_rules! invoke {
    ( $([$($field:expr),*]: $vtype:ty => $($func:ident$args:tt),* [$($newfunc:ident),*]; )+ ) => {{
        $(
            let x = vec![$($field),*];
            let y = vec![$($func$args),*];
            let z: Vec<$vtype> = vec![$($newfunc()),*];
            println!("{:#?}: {:#?} [{:#?}]", x, y, z);
        )+
    }};
}

fn main() {
    invoke!( 
        ["str1", "str2"]: i32 => test1(), test2() [test3, test4]; 
        ["str3", "str1"]: i32 => test1() [test3]; 
    );
}

fn test1() -> i32 { 42 }
fn test2() -> i32 { 42 }
fn test3() -> i32 { 42 }
fn test4() -> i32 { 42 }
```

> do I understand correctly that it's impossible to set `$args:tt` as optional, i.e. `test` vs `test()`.

There is no *optional*  modifier in macros that I am aware of. Usually, this is handled by having multiple parallel patterns:

```
macro_rules! thing {
    ($name:ident$args:tt) => { println!("a") };
    ($name:ident) => { println!("b") };
}

fn main() {
    thing!(foo);   // b
    thing!(foo()); // a
}
```

This doesn't appear to help your case because you wish to collect a bunch of A and then a bunch of B. This would allow a bunch of A-or-B. In grammar, it would be akin to

```
(A|B)* # This form
A*B*   # What you want
```

Comment: Thank you for awesome answer. Is it I understand correct that `$args:tt` impossible set as optional, i.e. `test vs test()`?

Comment: Just reading this answer and it should be updated. There is now an optional modifier for macros `$($x:ident)?`.